# How to get retweets with tweepy search api with geocode

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want to get results including retweets with Tweepy search API. I am getting it when I am not using geocode in my properties but when I use geocode I am getting only tweets in result not retweets.

```
cursor = api.search(q=searchString, geocode=geocode,
         count=20, lang='en', tweet_mode='extended')
```

Answer (score 1):

Twitter is very explicit in their documentation page [Filtering Tweets by location](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/filtering-tweets-by-location) that geocoding data is not available for retweets:

> **Important note**: Retweets can not have a Place attached to them, so if you use an operator such as has:geo, you will not match any Retweets